# Different return types with same function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing my own time unit class. This class provides a function for fetching a specific time value (milliseconds, seconds etc.). In order to prevent defining several get() functions for each time unit, I tried to implement a single function to serve this purpose.

```
typedef unsigned char u_char;
typedef unsigned short u_short;
typedef unsigned long long u_ll;
typedef u_ll DAYS_DTYPE;
typedef u_char HOURS_DTYPE;
typedef u_char MINUTES_DTYPE;
typedef u_char SECONDS_DTYPE;
typedef u_short MILLISECONDS_DTYPE;

// used class members; max. values are handled class-internal
DAYS_DTYPE          m_days;         // max.: 18.446.744.073.709.551.615
HOURS_DTYPE         m_hours;        // max.: 23
MINUTES_DTYPE       m_minutes;      // max.: 59
SECONDS_DTYPE       m_seconds;      // max.: 59
MILLISECONDS_DTYPE  m_milliseconds; // max.: 999

// class-internal enum
enum TimeUnit { Milliseconds, Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Days };

// used member function
template <typename T>
T getTime(TimeUnit unit)
{
    switch (unit)
    {
    case Milliseconds: return m_milliseconds;
    case Seconds: return m_seconds;
    case Minutes: return m_minutes;
    case Hours: return m_hours;
    case Days: return m_days;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

In order to fetch a specific time unit I have to use sth. like this:

```
getTime<MILLISECONDS_DTYPE>(Time::Milliseconds))
```

Is this approach acceptable? In case it's not, what should I change?

Comment: You might want to look closer at the [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library.

Comment: I don't think `getTime<MILLISECONDS_DTYPE>(Time::Milliseconds))` is any better than `getMillisec()`. Actually it seems worse. So why do you want to just define a single function?

Comment: @Lingxi To keep the amount of member functions as low as possible. But after all, it's not that minimalistic and clean as I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer something like this, as its less to type and compile-time, you probably always know what kind of time you need on compile-time and even if not you can hack around that problem, so:

```
template<TimeUnit time>
struct TimeUnitImpl
{ using type = decltype(m_milliseconds); };

template<>
struct TimeUnitImpl<Seconds>
{ using type = decltype(m_seconds); };

template<>
struct TimeUnitImpl<Minutes>
{ using type = decltype(m_minutes); };

template<>
struct TimeUnitImpl<Hours>
{ using type = decltype(m_hours); };

template<>
struct TimeUnitImpl<Days>
{ using type = decltype(m_days); };

// used member function
template <TimeUnit unit = Seconds>
typename TimeUnitImpl<unit>::type getTime()
{
    switch (unit)
    {
    case Milliseconds: return m_milliseconds;
    case Seconds: return m_seconds;
    case Minutes: return m_minutes;
    case Hours: return m_hours;
    case Days: return m_days;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

In order to fetch a specific time unit you would have to use something like this:

```
getTime<Time::Milliseconds>()
```

Try it [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51fc3564740411ef)!

In order to keep a "good style" I would change the function name here, too. Probably simply to `time` rather than `getTime`, that `get`-prefix is pretty much useless here.

But anyways, you might consider just using `getTimeMilliseconds` or something like that.

Comment: So if my needed time unit differs from the default parameter list, I still have to use something like this: getTime<Time::Hours, HOURS_DTYPE>(). In the end there's not much difference in to used length at all.

Comment: I tested your code and implemented some basic checks for correct data type conversion, but as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de74d5111abda05d), some checks, beside of those for u_char of course, fail!

Comment: @NaCI thx, site was updating to slow :D

Comment: This is probably more typing then just writing separate getters, for both the class user and class writer.

Comment: @T.C. Thats why I suggested just using something like `getTimeMilliseconds`.

Comment: In this case, I might have `TimeUnitImpl` store a `static constexpr` pointer or (probably more likely) pointer-to-member to the field, and just do a dereference in `getTime()`, to avoid repeating the name.